# NullPointerException At Creating view with fragment inside fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, adapter

When i start the activity that contains a NavigationDrawer with a TabLayout inside it appears a bug report that says that viewPager must not be null.
Here is the code where the error occurs, in the line where is viewPager.adapter = adapter ...

Hope that someone can tell me how to fix this.

I was thinking that i need a method that creates those fragments

```
class fragment_nav_home : Fragment() {

    private fun setUpTabs() {
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)

        adapter.addFragment(fragment_tab_artists(), "Artists")
        adapter.addFragment(fragment_tab_agencies(), "Agencies")

        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setUpTabs()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // setUpTabs()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_home, container, false)
    }
}
```

The functions addFragment cames from the next Kotlin class

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
    FragmentPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {
    private val lstFragments = ArrayList<Fragment>();
    private val lstFragmentsTitles = ArrayList<String>();

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return lstFragments.size
    }

    override fun getItem(i: Int): Fragment {
        return lstFragments[i]
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(i: Int): CharSequence? {
        return lstFragmentsTitles[i]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {

        lstFragments.add(fragment)
        lstFragmentsTitles.add(title)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `viewPager` variable is null, so you can't set an `adapter` property on it, because `null` doesn't have that.

Where are you setting `viewPager`? It doesn't look like you're using the view binding library, so you need to do a `viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)` or whatever, e.g. in `onCreateView`:

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_home, container, false)
viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
return view
```

or if you're using Kotlin synthetics (where the IDs in a layout are converted into variables with the same name, so you can just access the views without needing to look them up):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_nav_home.*
```

in which case you need a `ViewPager` in your XML layout with an ID of "viewPager``.

Right now it's null because you haven't assigned it, or it doesn't exist (if it's being automatically assigned)